# How to remove /index from url

Tags: php, html, url, heroku

I coded my own website and on what I would like to be the homepage is https://example.com/index I was able to remove the .html by adding some stuff to .htaccess but I can't get rid of the /index. I use Heroku to host my website. It's connected to my GitHub repository with all the code and whenever I push changes to GitHub it automatically deploys the website. Is there anything else I can add to the .htaccess file or maybe renaming the index.html for or something?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to you .htaccess file. This will do it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Doing this didn't work. Now when I want to go to my about page or any other pages I have it no longer works. It just redirects back to the home page which has /index.html again